# Replace space with underscore in all table names in database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to replace all space (' ') with a underscore in all the table names in a database using PhpMyAdmin.

Ex:
Table 1 --> Table_1

I was wondering if this is possible. I know it's possible to do this for columns but I was wondering if someone could write me something for tables. I don't use PhpMyAdmin very often, but I installed it in this case becuase it works easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run a query like this to generate the SQL that will perform a rename:

```
SELECT CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', table_name, ' TO ' , REPLACE(table_name, ' ', '_') , ';') 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema_name';
```

Remember to substitute `your_schema_name` for whatever your database is called.

To run the query in phpMyAdmin you can click the SQL tab at the top of the window, then paste the SQL into the box. The result of the above query will be SQL generated based off of the existing table names. Just copy this resulting SQL back into the textbox and run it again to perform the renames.

Comment: I executed it and it came back with a CONCAT and options. What do I do from here? I can't copy this back into the SQL

Comment: You should be able to copy the contents of the CONCAT row, click SQL at the top again, paste it and run it. Then the table names will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you could do this in a stored procedure, but it is easy enough to have a query generate a script for you:

```
SELECT CONCAT('RENAME TABLE `'
     , table_name
     , '` TO `'
     , REPLACE(table_name, ' ', '_')
     , '`;'
    ) AS renameQuery 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mySchema' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '% %'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also rename all table with one command:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('RENAME TABLE '
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(
      CONCAT('`',TABLE_NAME,'` TO ', REPLACE(TABLE_NAME,' ','_'))
    SEPARATOR ', '),';') AS query
FROM information_schema.Tables
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourschema'
AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '% %';
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> SELECT   CONCAT('RENAME TABLE '     ,GROUP_CONCAT(       CONCAT('`',TABLE_NAME,'` TO ', REPLACE(TABLE_NAME,' ','_'))     SEPARATOR ', '),';') AS query FROM information_schema.Tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourschema' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '% %';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| query                                                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| RENAME TABLE `esercizio 1` TO esercizio_1, `my_table 1` TO my_table_1, `t 1` TO t_1; |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourschema]>
```